# 'this.variable' object element in the separate file

Tags: javascript, html, this

HTML code:

```
<input class="jscolor" id="color-picker">

   <div id="rect" class="rect"></div>

   <script src="jscolor.js"></script>
   <script src="skrypt.js"></script>
```

Javascript code:

```
 function update(jscolor) {
        document.getElementById('rect').style.backgroundColor = '#' +   jscolor;
}

window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById('color-picker').onchange = update(this.jscolor);
}
```

in sample above function 'update' don't works correctly, but if I inducting this function in html

```
<input class="jscolor" id="color-picker" onchange="update(this.jscolor)">
```

is allright.

So my question is how, following the good trends, get rid of event induct from html and move it to separate javascript file?

Comment: By "following the good trends" I'd use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ...onchange = update(this.jscolor)
> ```

This executes `update` at the time when you attach the event handler.

> ```
> onchange="update(this.jscolor)"
> ```

This executes `update` at the time the event fires.

To programmatically attach an event handler which fires at the time of the event, do this:

```
document.getElementById('color-picker').addEventListener('change', function () {
    update(this.jscolor);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should address `this` within the function body:

```
document.getElementById('color-picker').onchange = function () {
    update(this.jscolor);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a best-practice unobtrusive approach, try something like the snippet below.

***N.B.*** Evidently the snippet below is a very simple example because `.rect` will only change to one `background-color` (red), but you can modify the script so that `.rect` can change to any number of `background-color` values.

```js
var jscolor = 'rgb(255,0,0)';

function update(jscolor) {
    var rect = document.getElementsByClassName('rect')[0];
    rect.style.backgroundColor = jscolor;
}

function colorUpdate() {
var colorPicker = document.getElementsByClassName('color-picker')[0];
colorPicker.addEventListener('click',function(){update(jscolor);},false);
}

window.addEventListener('load',colorUpdate,false);
```

```css
.color-picker, .rect {
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin-right: 40px;
}

.rect {
background-color: rgb(236,236,236);
}
```

```html
<div class="color-picker">Click Me to give Rect a red background</div>
<div class="rect">Rect</div>
```